# Two instances of pyvirtualdisplay (xvfb) won't run at the same time

Tags: python, selenium, xvfb, pyvirtualdisplay

So I have a small script which uses pyvirtualdisplay to make a virtual display to run some selenium tests. I have tested the same code on my windows computer and both run just fine at the same time. Which leads me to believe that the problem is with pyvirtualdisplay. After looking on here there were a couple people with the same problem as me but none really got resolved so I am really hoping one of you might be able to help me out here.

from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

```
def function_one():
    display_one = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
    display_one.start()
    driver_one = webdriver.Chrome()

    # Do stuff here

    driver_one.quit()
    display_one.stop()

def following(self, account=""):
    display_two = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
    display_two.start()
    driver_two = webdriver.Chrome()

    # Do other stuff here

    driver_two.quit()
    display_two.stop()
```

Doing this in python. So yes any help would be greatly appreciated.

Error Raised

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash
from unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from tab crashed
```